# Error related to pandas datareader with jupyter notebook on mac

Tags: python, pandas, datareader

I am a french beginner in programming in python. When I want to import datas from yahoo finance i got this error :

`APPL = wb.DataReader('APPL', data_source = 'yahoo', start='2005-1-1')

[here is the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nM6lJ.png)
[here is the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lCdw6.png)
Can you help me to resolve this ?
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

It might be caused by Yahoo Finance changing its API.

Try pip install yfiance module:

```
pip install yfinance
```

If you're using Google Colab:

```
!pip install yfinance
```

The following code works for me currently:

```
import yfinance as yf
data = yf.download("AAPL", start="2005-1-1")
```